# In hyperlink formula field custom label is not fetching the value - salesforce

Tags: formula, formula-field, customlabel, hyperlink

Syntax of hyperlink formula is -

```
HYPERLINK("URL," "Display Text," "_self")
```

I am using following formula for hyperlink in formula field.

```
HYPERLINK('/apex/Core_VFP182_Documill?id='+Id+'&'+'templateID='+$Label.Core_Template_Id, "$Label.Candidate_Profile", "_self")
```

My URL is correct but $Label.Candidate_Profile is not fetching value.

Showing as below

[image]

Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use label `$Label.Candidate_Profile` without Quotes

```
HYPERLINK('/apex/Core_VFP182_Documill?id='+Id+'&'+'templateID='+$Label.Core_Template_Id, $Label.Candidate_Profile, "_self")
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working.